# c# open url in chrome with hash (#)

Tags: c#, google-chrome, hash, process

I'm trying to open a url in Chrome from c# and retain the hash (#).
Example:

```
string command = "http://127.0.0.1/test.html#foobar";
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(command) { UseShellExecute = true };
Process.Start(ps);
```

Everything after and including the hash (#) is lost when starting the process. I can run Chrome manually from the command prompt including the hash in the url

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe
>   127.0.0.1/test.html#foobar

and the hash is retained when the default browser is set to IE or FireFox.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div style="height:1000px; background: #ccc; width: 100%"></div>
<a name="foobar">foobar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I do not want to presume the user wants to use chrome, I need this to work in what ever the users default browser is. It works when the user's default browser is IE or Fire Fox, but the hash is lost when the users default browser is Chrome.

Comment: Try explicitly running Chrome in the command?

Answer (score 1):

The command to open a URL in the default browser is `start myURL`, not just `myURL`.

You'll need to execute the command:

> start "127.0.0.1/test.html#foobar"

Note that the quotes need to be in the resulting string, not in C#; the C# code for that would be:

```
string command = @"start" + @"""127.0.0.1/test.html#foobar""";
```

Comment: I need this to work in what ever browser is the user has set as their default. I don't want to force users to use Chrome, I just need it to pass the hash in to the url IF they are using Chrome.

Comment: @SteveHansen Then why did you specifically tag the question as chrome, as about opening it in chrome, and use `chrome.exe` in your example of what you did when using the shell directly?  First determine what you want to do in the shell, then worry about translating it to C#.  In any case, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: As I explained in the question, this works in IE and FireFox. This is problematic if the users default browser is set to Chrome. The issue is specific to opening a URL that contains a hash in Chrome. The example of starting using the shell directly illustrated that the hash can be retained in Chrome, but when run via C# (as illustrated), the hash is lost.

Answer (score 0):

My default browser is chrome and this command works perfectly correctly:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"http://www.bitterminion.com/excel-launchpad#gopro");
```

The "#gopro" remains intact.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. Just tested it with .NET 2, 3, 3.5, and 4. All had the same result. Does it not work correctly when you execute that exact line of code with your configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't work for me. I'm running Window 8, Chrome 23.0.1271.97. I have tested on a few different Win8 machines with the same result.